# curl script not using cookies correctly

Tags: php, cookies, curl

hi there i am trying to creat a php script to login to my tesco account but for some reason the cookies are not working please help here is my script below and also an example of my script below so u can check it out .

[Check it out it does not work](http://cyber-hosted.com/CH/n.php)

```
<?php
$url = "https://secure.tesco.com/register/default.aspx?vstore=0";
//
$h = curl_init();
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "form=fSignin&from=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.tesco.com%2Fclubcard%2Fmyaccount%2Fhome.aspx&formData=bmV3UmVnPWZhbHNlJg%3D%3D&loginID=test%40hotmail.com&password=test&seamlesswebtag=&confirm-signin.x=47&confirm-signin.y=18");
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'tmpfile.tmp');
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'tmpfile.tmp');
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'tmpfile.tmp');
//
$result = curl_exec($h);
echo $result;
?>
```

can someplease help me fix this so it gets and uses the cookies properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need this line

```
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'tmpfile.tmp');
```

try removing it, if still has a problem, try to create tmpfile.tmp and set chmod to 777.

Comment: i have got that to work now i have another error visit my website it says object moved here i click the here but nothing

Comment: Maybe you should set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, read more about it here http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php